# Hadoop security using Apache DS / Apache Directory Studio

Tags: java, hadoop, ldap, kerberos, apacheds

I am interested in [Apache DS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/) and [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/). Currently I am working in Hadoop and analysing ways to secure hadoop cluster; LDAP and Kerberos are parts of the above product; On analysis I have some questions,

1) Is it possible to make use of Apache Directory Studio UI to secure hadoop cluster? If yes any one  please provide us any UG?

2) I just checked the below [Kerberos-Integration tutorial](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/kerberos-ug/2.2-ldap-server-config.html). But most of the links just hold the content ‘TODO…’ . When this will be updated?

3) Windows distribution of Apache Directory Studio has Kerberos installed built in? If yes how to enable it / make it to work to generate tickets?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. In the Hadoop source codes, Apache Directory is used for integration-test. You reference the   relevant codes for your question.
2. This section seems empty for a long time. I think it would not be updated soon.
3. I have no idea for this. Most of time I am working on Linux.